# Should number of iterations of PBKDF2 stay secret?

Tags: cryptography, pbkdf2, password-hash

Let's say I encrypt my passwords with PBKDF2 and store it somewhere. Now let's say it was stolen and the hacker, who stole it knows it was hashed with PBKDF2.

Does a knowledge of number of iterations make it easier to brute force the password?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Please ask on https://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Moved my question to relevant stackexchange:
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/60860/should-number-of-iterations-of-pbkdf2-stay-secret

Related question:
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/25595/is-there-a-tangible-benefit-in-keeping-the-number-of-pbkdf-iterations-secret-and